# How to solve this question about positive definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

$A$ is a positive definite matrix. Prove that there must be a column vector $X$ whose components are all positive and the components of $AX$ are all positive, too.
I think there exists a matrice D, D is invertible and A=D'*D. There exists an orthogonal matrix O and x1,x2,~,xn>0, st. A=O'*diag(x1,x2,~,xn)*O. But I don't know how to continue afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments